# xamarin forms collectionview multiple pre selection from ListView Source Item

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have a collectionview fill with a modeldata this data come to normal xaml.cs:

```
          <CollectionView x:Name="Especialidadrec"
                               
                                
                                SelectionMode="Multiple"  
                                SelectionChanged="collectionView_SelectionChanged"

                                >
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate  x:DataType="local1:SpecialityApi">
                          
                                <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="10"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                       Text="{Binding Idesp , Converter={StaticResource stringEspecialidad}}" />
                            
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

and i have a listview fill with a strings ID and they are equals to many fields in collectionview Idesp this data came from MVM:

```
               <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Specialitiess, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                        
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate  x:DataType="sys:String">
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                       Text="{Binding . , Converter={StaticResource stringEspecialidad}}"
                                              
                                                />
                                   
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

I need use SelectedItems on colecction view to PRE SELECT fields equals to string arrary in list view....... many trys i cant find the solution

Comment: It’s difficult to give a precise answer without knowing anything about your data.  But generally you would use LINQ to query your data for any items that match the list of ids, and use the results of that query to bind to SelectedItems

Answer (score 0):

For this,you can add a field `SelectedItems` to your viewmodel and bind it to the property `SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"` for your collectionview.

```
    ObservableCollection<object> selectedItems;
    public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedItems
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItems != value)
            {
                selectedItems = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I created a demo and achieved this funciton, you can refer to the following code:

1.create a view model for the page

`MyViewModel.cs`

```
 public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public List<string> Specialities { get; set; }

    ObservableCollection<object> selectedItems;
    public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedItems
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItems != value)
            {
                selectedItems = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel() {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item {  Idesp = "01",Name="test1"});
        Items.Add(new Item {  Idesp = "02",Name="test2"});
        Items.Add(new Item {  Idesp = "03",Name="test3"});


        Specialities = new List<string>();
        Specialities.Add("01");
        Specialities.Add("03");

        //SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<object>() { Items[0], Items[2] };

        SelectedItems =new ObservableCollection<object>();

        // here you can filter the Items for preselection.
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            foreach (var str in Specialities)
            {
                if (str.Equals(item.Idesp))
                {
                    SelectedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }

        }
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

2.Usage example

`MainPage.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FormListViewApp1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView        x:Name="Especialidadrec" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                               SelectionMode="Multiple"  
                               SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"
                               SelectionChanged="Especialidadrec_SelectionChanged"  >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Large"></Label>
                        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="10"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                       Text="{Binding Idesp}" />
                    </StackLayout>


                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Specialities}"  
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell DetailColor="Black"
                                      TextColor="Black"
                                      Text="{Binding .}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
        }

        private void Especialidadrec_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

**Note:**

Remember to define the type of `SelectedItems` as follows:

```
    ObservableCollection<object> selectedItems;
    public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedItems
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedItems != value)
            {
                selectedItems = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I find that if I use `object` not the type of the Item of collectionview(`Item`), the effect of multiple preselection will not appear normally.